# Как заставить PyCharm рисовать схемы с плагином plantUML?

Tags: python, pycharm, graphviz

Плагин не отрисовывает схемы. Ошибка изображена на картинке.
Что сделано:

1. Переменная окружения GRAPHVIZ _DOT ='/usr/bin/dot'  добавлена в ./bashrc
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Путь /usr/bin/dot указан в settings в PyCharm
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Проверена работоспособность graphviz  через вывод в файл echo 'digraph { a -> b }' | dot -Tsvg > output.svg
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   4.Диаграмма работает, отрисована на другом компьютере.

Comment: Добавьте `/` в начало, чтоб был полный путь `/usr/bin/dot`

Comment: К сожалению не получилось все равно.

Comment: Вопрос решен установкой галочки в настройках Remote rendering.